# Generate thumbnail from remote jpeg without downloading

Tags: http, jpeg, thumbnails, exif

I want to load the EXIF thumbnail preview stored in a jpeg image located on a remote server, without having to download the whole image. The server does not support resuming.

Is this possible? In detail, can I assume that the thumbnail image data is alway before the full image data so that I only have to download a maximum of (e.g.) 100kb which I can parse for the thumbnail data?

Comment: Is it possible to predict where the EXIF data will be stored in the file?  If so, maybe you could do a `HEAD` request to get the file size, then do a `GET` with a `Range` header to get the partial content of the EXIF block based on the image size...

Comment: Are the JPEG files generated by the same application? If so, then the thumbnail should be the same dimensions and encoded in the file the same way each time.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same question and found this Greasemonkey script which adds thumbnail images to an Apache auto index page.

- https://userscripts.org/scripts/review/5390

For each JPEG image link it issues a range request for the jpeg / jfif header, parses the thumbnail offset and thumbnail length tag then issues a further range request for the thumbnail, creates a data uri and assigns it to a new img object.

Unfortunately it only works for certain JPEG file formats.